# eliminating rows and combining from a file

Tags: python

i have a file with a data that looks like this:

```
A   1        23        36  -3   ABC
A   1        23        36  -3   ABD
A   1        23        36  -3   CLA
B   2        21        4   -6   PQR
B   2        21        4   -6   CAP
C   5        47        3   -4   FM
C   10       54        6   -5   AKN
D   15        76       3   -4   LGA
D   20        76       10  -6   MHA
```

I am comparing each row for the first 5 columns and if they are equal, im joinining the last column using for loops, which takes a lot of time.

the Output is like:

```
A   1        23        36  -3   ABC,ABD,CLA
B   2        21        4   -6   PQR,CAP
C   5        47        3   -4   FM
C   10       54        6   -5   AKN
D   15        76       3   -4   LGA
D   20        76       10  -6   MHA
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this? the data is stored as text files and rows are read line by line.

Comment: sort, split columns, grouby... PROFIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does that:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)

with open('/tmp/cols.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_data=line.strip().split()
        d['\t'.join(line_data[0:5])].append(line_data[5])

for k in sorted(d.keys(), 
                key=lambda s: (s.split()[0], tuple(map(int, s.split()[1:])))):
    print(k, '\t',', '.join(d[k]))
```

Prints:

```
A   1   23  36  -3   ABC, ABD, CLA
B   2   21  4   -6   PQR, CAP
C   5   47  3   -4   FM
C   10  54  6   -5   AKN
D   15  76  3   -4   LGA
D   20  76  10  -6   MHA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = sorted(x.rsplit(' ', 1) for x in YOUR_FILE.read().split('\n'))

new_lines = [x + ','.join(i[1] for i in y) for x,y in
             itertools.groupby(lines, operator.itemgetter(0))]

print('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

Comment: OP says: *I am comparing each row for the first 5 columns*... The two `D`s aren't supposed to be grouped for instance...

Comment: Sorry - didn't see the `r` in the split... I'd still be tempted to split from the left and normalise out the whitespace between columns and group by those though...